# Display a message after login - Angular 5

Tags: typescript, angular5, message

Hello/good evening people
I'm new to typescript and angular 5 and I want to create a service that displays a message for the users after every login. This is what I did:

It's a text area that will submit the text that will be shown in the Home Page after the login action. 
I mean, the admin will write and submit the message via this form and then it will be displayed for the users.

```js
export class NewsLetterComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() onNewsText = new EventEmitter<string>();

  newsText: string;
  constructor(private _router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() { 
    this.newsText = null;
  }

  onclick(newsText: string) {
    this.newsText;
    this.onNewsText.emit(newsText);
 
  }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid" >
<form>
     <div class="form-group">
    <textarea #newsText class="form-control"  rows="3"></textarea>
  </div>
   <button type="submit" (click)="onclick(newsText.value)"class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Publish</button>
</form>
</div>
```

and displaying it in the Home Page:

```html
<header [user]="user"  (logout)="logout()"> Loading...</header>
 <p-messages #newsletter [(value)]="newsletterText"></p-messages> 
<content class="admin-page">
<sidenav></sidenav> 
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<content>
```

```js
export class AdminPageComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
@ViewChild('newsletterComponenet') newsletterComponenet: NewsLetterComponent;
@Input('newsletterText') newsletterText: String;

//the rest of the code *

  ngOnChanges() {
    if (this.newsletterText && this.newsletterText.length) {
       this.msgs.push({ severity: 'info', summary: this.newsletterText });
    }
  }
```

This doesn't work for sure, and I don't know if what I am doing is leading to the right way or not.
Can someone help me on this?

P.S. I Googled but could not find satisfactory answer anywhere

Comment: Sorry, but this won't work anyway. Even if I'd show you how to set up this service properly, you still need some kind of a database and a server in the background to store and get the message written by the admin. Every Computer runs it's own copy of your program. A message emitted locally on the admin's PC will never reach an other person's PC without a Server and a Database in the background.

Comment: okay so the first thing i have to do is to create an object to store the message and send it to the Home Page component of every user ?

Comment: Simply spoke, yes. But there's a lot more effort behind it, though. You need to set up and program a server to handle the data transfer. You have to have a database table where you can put those messages in. If you have achieved this an the message is successfully store in the database, then you can create a client side service that gets those messages from the server an provides them on the login page.

Comment: aaaah i got it, it means that the message must be stored in the database ( i already have one ) and then the Home page will display the last update

Comment: Not exactly. You have to build a service that sends the message to the Server when you click the Submit-button in the NewsLetterComponent. The Server stores this message. Now you have to create another Service for your HomePage that sends, after Login, a request to the Server in order to get the latest messages. Both services are independent and the EventEmitter() in your NewsletterComponent has nothing to do with it at all!

Comment: now it's clear :) i'm going to work on this, it seems more logic than the EventEmitter thing x')) Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the streps:

1. build a service that sends the message to the Server when you click the Submit-button in the NewsLetterComponent.
2. The Server stores this message.
3. create another Service for your HomePage that sends, after Login, a request to the Server in order to get the latest messages.

Both services are independent and the `EventEmitter()` in your `NewsletterComponent` has nothing to do with it at all!